# Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: Invalid date literal [$C6]. Date literals should be of form yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: google-sheets

Hello where is the problem

Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: Invalid date literal [Sheet2!C6]. Date literals should be of form yyyy-MM-dd.

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:P, "select count(M) where B=date 'Sheet2!C6' ")
```

i'm try to create filtre date

I don't why is param "Sheet2!C6" not working !!??

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=query(Sheet1!A2:P, "select count(M) where B=date'"&text(Sheet2!C6,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

**OR**

```js
=counta(ifna(filter(Sheet1!M2:M,Sheet1!B2:B=Sheet2!C6)))
```